# How Do we can give dynamic data for a form field in admin form(ui-component) in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, adminform, custom-field

I need to add note to the form field using notice tag. for example

```
 <notice translate="true">Image size should be equal to some(here I
 need to pass dynamic value)</notice>
```

**form.xml**

```
 <field name="image" sortOrder="60" formElement="fileUploader">
            <settings>
                <notice translate="true">Image size should be equal to some(here I need to pass dynamic value)</notice>
                <label translate="true">Image</label>
                <componentType>fileUploader</componentType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <fileUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>102400</maxFileSize>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="string" name="url">a/b/c</param>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>x_y/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                    </settings>
                </fileUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

Comment: how to create form using ui-component? or simple

Comment: I have created form using ui-component

Comment: <uiComponent name="vendor_department_addform"/>

wait am write full code in ans

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that extending the method `Vendor\Module\Model\DataProvider::getMeta()`

```
public function getMeta()
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();
    $yourString = 'Dynamic Content Here';
    $config = [
            'the_field_set_name' => [
                'children' => [
                    'image' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'notice' => $yourString,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $meta = array_merge_recursive($meta, $config);
    

    return $meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

view/adminhtml/layout/form_index_index.xml

```
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="vendor_department_addform"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

view/adminhtml/ui_component/vendor_department_addform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_department_addform.vendor_department_addform_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_department_addform.vendor_department_addform_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Department Information</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Add\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="reset" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Add\ResetButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Add\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>

    <dataSource name="vendor_department_addform_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_department_addform_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">department_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="vendor/department/save"/>
        </settings>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="department_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add new department</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
        <field name="department_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">jobportal</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">jobportal</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="identifier">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Identifier</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">jobportal</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">identifier</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">jobportal</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="sort_order">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sort order</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">jobportal</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">sort_order</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Department\Source\SelectOption</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">jobportal</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <!-- <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item> -->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Vendor\Module\Model\DataProvider.php this is use for form data

```
namespace Vendor\module\Model;

use Vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Department\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory,

        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $pageCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->meta = $this->prepareMeta($this->meta);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        /** @var $page \Custom\Module\Model\Messages */
        foreach ($items as $page) {
            $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
        }
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->loadedData);die;
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But my question is I need to add note to the form field. In that note message I need to pass dynamic values or data. For example <notice> Image size should be equal to some(here I need to pass dynamic value) size</notice>

Comment: dataprovider.php handle dynamic data

Comment: Please see the updated post

Comment: <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_ModuleName/js/form/element/options</item>
change using js