# Product Listing Ui Component xml file not overriding in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, layout, uicomponent

I need to override `module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml` file in my custom module. I have copy the core magento file in my module at `view\adminhtml\ui_component` but its not working. is there anything else i have to do.

Comment: add sourse & collection mode in di.xml & add same xml in your custom list xml

Comment: Did not get you what you are try to say

Comment: fist you have to assing product collection in di.xml
after use that source collection in your custom list xml

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209804/how-do-we-can-give-dynamic-data-for-a-form-field-in-admin-formui-component-in/209811#209811

Comment: vendor_department_addform_data_source this id get form di.xml

Comment: I don't want to update the collection just need to update the columns in product_listing.xml file

Comment: got it check my ans

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 www.magebuzz.com
*/
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
       <column name="custom_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Field</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then created the UI class under [COMPANY]/[MODULE]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php

```
<?php

namespace RLTS\Helloworld\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Category extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{

   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
   {
      $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
      if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
         foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
         //print_r($item);die;
         $productId=$item['entity_id'];
         //$product=$this->_productloader->create()->load($p_id);
         //$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loa‌​d($p_id);
         //$productId = $p_id;
         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
         $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
         //$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $categories=array();
         if(count($cats) ){
            foreach($cats as $cat){
               $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat);
                $categories[]=$category->getName();
            }
         }
         $item[$fieldName]=implode(',',$categories);
         }
      }
   return $dataSource;
   }
}
```

This is for just DEMO

```
<column name="amount" class="M [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Amount</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>      

namespace [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $status = $order->getData("export_status");

                switch ($status) {
                    case "0":
                        $export_status = "No";
                        break;
                    case "1";
                        $export_status = "Yes";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $export_status = "Failed";
                        break;

                }

                // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return export_status
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $export_status;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will add new column in the grid but what i am trying to do is to add inline Edit in product list grid. I have worked on core file but now i want to use that core file in my module.

Comment: <column name="amount" class="[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Columnt">
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Amount</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

Comment: check my code after "This is for just DEMO" line

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't this kind of functionality. I simply want to override product_listing.xml

Comment: <column name="custom_field"> this for culumns name available in product table then class="M [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status"> not require and also not require below php code

Comment: custom_field is table  column name